# Change value of all properties inside array if any property value is modified swift (wiiSet)

Tags: ios, swift

I want to change value of "isSelected" property of all objects inside array if any object's "isSelected" property within that array is changed. i want to do it in willSet event.  i have issue that how to get reference of array (which holds this object) in willSet event of "isSelected" property.

```
class Survey: NSObject {
var question = "N/A"
var options = [SurveyOption]()
init(Question question:String,options:[String]) {
    self.question = question
    self.options.appendContentsOf(SurveyOption.GetSurveyOption(options))
}

class SurveyOption: NSObject {
    var option = "N/A"
    var isSelected = false

    init(Option option:String) {
        self.option = option
    }

    class func GetSurveyOption(options:[String]) -> [SurveyOption]{
        var surveyOptions = [SurveyOption]()
        for option in options{
            surveyOptions.append(SurveyOption(Option: option))
        }
        return surveyOptions
    }
}


class func GetSurveyQuestions() -> [Survey]{
    let questions = [Survey]()


    return questions
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSNotificationCenter`.

1) In your class Register for notification `NOTIFICATION_IS_SELECTED_VALUE_CHANGED` in init

it will look like,

```
init(Option option:String) {
    self.option = option
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
    self,
    selector: "isSelectedValueChanged:",
    name: NOTIFICATION_IS_SELECTED_VALUE_CHANGED,
    object: nil)

}
```

2) Add selector `isSelectedValueChanged:` in your class,

```
func isSelectedValueChanged(notification: NSNotification){     
    //do stuff
    let changedValue = (notification.object as! NSNumber).boolValue
}
```

3) Add `didSet{ }` for property `isSelected`, and post notification if property changed, it will look like

```
    var isSelected = false {
        didSet{
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(NOTIFICATION_IS_SELECTED_VALUE_CHANGED, object: NSNumber(bool: isSelected));
        }
    }
```

Whenever value of property `isSelected` will be changed, notification will be fired, and all the object of class `SurveyOption` will be notified, and the method `isSelectedValueChanged:` will be called with new of that particuler object.